# Why is the javascript for ID: overlay2 not displaying correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two overlays that display when you click a button. When I have a single button, the function works correctly. But when I copy and paste; and change the messaging on the second overlay, both display the same message. I tried changing the ID tag names and it doesn't work. Could someone explain why?

```
    `function on() {
     document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = "block";
     }

     function off() {
     document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
     }

     function on() {
     document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "block";
      }

     function off() {
     document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "none";
     }

     <body>


     <table width="600px" border="0" bordercolor="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
      <!-- start of Sku 1-->
      <td width="250" align="center"> 
     <div class="polaroid">
     <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
     <div id="text">Co flex , the best product in the world. Yes this is a rainbow color product but 
      loving this is the collest thing you could ever do. Im serious this is the best product in the 
       planet. Let me tell you what you need to play with  so that you could get this amazing 
       product</div>
      </div>
     <button id="btn1" onclick="on()">Product Information</button>
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.shopmedvet.com/images/large/COFLEX-VET4.jpg" alt"coflex" 
        style="width: "350px">

       <div class="container">

      <!-- start of form submission code-->
                                       <div class="form-group " width="281">
     <label for="field_330"  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; 
         font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">SKU: 46711-212X
        <h4>Retail: <h3 style="font-size:20px">$9.99</h3></h4>

        <div class=SKuQTY>
        <label for="field_328" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; 
           font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">Quantity</label>
                                                                 </div>                                                                                                                  
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="field_328" id="field_328" value="" size="4" 
             maxlength="6" > </div>   <span class="help-block">
             <br>
             </br>
             <label for="field_329"  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans- 
                   serif'; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">Make A Deal</label>

                    <div class="Sku1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="field_329" id="field_329" value="" 
                  size="4" maxlength="6" >
                   </div> 
                     </div>
                         </div>
                  </div>                                                     </td>
                                                                                   <!-- start of Sku 
                              1-->
           <td width="250" align="center"> 
         <div class="polaroid2">
         <div id="overlay2" onclick="off()">
         <div id="text2"> helllo</div>
          </div>

           <button id="btn2" onclick="on()">Product Information</button>
          <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.shopmedvet.com/images/large/COFLEX-VET4.jpg" 
         alt"coflex" style="width: "350px">

           <div class="container2">

                            <!-- start of form submission code-->
                                       <div class="form-group " width="281">
              <label for="field_330"  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans- 
               serif'; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">SKU: 46711-212X
               <h4>Retail: <h3 style="font-size:20px">$9.99</h3></h4>

                <div class=SKuQTY>
                <label for="field_328" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans- 
                        serif'; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">Quantity</label>
                                                                 </div>                                                                                                                  
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="field_328" id="field_328" 
                       value="" size="4" maxlength="6" > </div>   <span class="help-block">
                      <br>
                         </br>
                       <label for="field_329"  style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 
                        Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">Make A Deal</label>

                      <div class="Sku1">
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="field_329" id="field_329" 
                      value="" size="4" maxlength="6" >
                       </div> 
                     </div>
                         </div>
                  </div>                                                     </td>                    


                     </table>

                     </body>
```

Comment: Run the code through your head. You declare a function called `on`. You say it must display `btn1`. A couple of lines later, you redeclare the function `on`, saying that actually, it must display `overlay2`. You're overwriting the previous version. Instead of copy/pasting, you should think: how can I write this function only once, but make it work for multiple elements. Think "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself). Also, just to clarify: Java has nothing to do with Javascript :)

Comment: I don't see any jQuery here. Is there a reason it's tagged?

Comment: Please validate your HTML and format it properly. There are a bunch of errors in it. It wouldn't hurt to simplify for the sake of this question, too. We don't need to see _all_ your laundry. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. I did not reuse your HTML, since it's will just clutter this example with things which are not important here.

In the example below, I created a single overlay and popup. It will be reused by all items. I tried commenting the code as much as I could and making it as simple as possible, but don't hesitate to ask if something is not clear.

On a side note, here are some tips:

- **Think DRY** *(Don't Repeat Yourself)*. If you catch yourself copy/pasting code, ask yourself how you can do the work once, and make it work for multiple identical things. This implies: don't use IDs with `1`, `2`, `3` in them. Instead, since the items share the same behavior, use a class. That's the whole purpose of them. IDs are unique, classes are shared. Don't rewrite entire functions when a single thing changes in them. This will help you later, when you want to change that function. You'll only have to do it once. What a pleasure!
- **Don't mix HTML/JS/CSS**. In your code, you were attaching event listeners in the HTML with `onclick="..."`. Again, you're repeating yourself. If you want to change something, you'll have to do it everywhere. Same thing for styles which are shared by multiple elements. Use classes, and style those classes in separate CSS.

```js
// Get all items on the page, the overlay so on
var items        = document.querySelectorAll('.item'),
    overlay      = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    closeBtn     = document.getElementById('popup-close-btn'),
    popupContent = document.getElementById('popup-content');

// Setup each of them
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  setupItem(items[i]); // Using a function here will make it easier (scope of `i`)
}

// Allow closing the popup
overlay.addEventListener('click', closePopup);

function setupItem(item) {
  // Get the button inside this item
  var btn = item.querySelector('.show-info-btn');
  // And the info associated to it
  var content = item.querySelector('.info').innerHTML;
  // Set up a click event listener
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() { openPopup(content); });
}

function openPopup(content) {
  // Set the popup content
  popupContent.innerHTML = content;
  // Show the overlay
  overlay.classList.add('open');
}

function closePopup(e) {
  // If we clicked on the overlay or close button (not on the popup itself)
  if (e.target === closeBtn || e.target === overlay) {
    // Hide the overlay
    overlay.classList.remove('open');
  }
}
```

```css
/* Non-important CSS was minified to avoid cluttering the example */                                           body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}.item{float:left;border:1px solid #ddd;text-align:center;padding:.5em}.item img{width:110px;height:100px;display:block;margin: 0 auto}h3{margin: 0.2em}.item .info{display:none}#overlay{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);cursor:pointer;display:none}#overlay.open{display:block}#popup{width:400px;max-width:90%;margin:1em auto;background:#fff;padding:.8em;position:relative;padding-top:20px;cursor:default}#popup-close-btn{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:32px;height:32px;opacity:.5;cursor:pointer}#popup-close-btn:hover{opacity:1}#popup-close-btn:before,#popup-close-btn:after{position:absolute;left:15px;top:6px;content:' ';height:20px;width:2px;background-color:#333}#popup-close-btn:before{transform:rotate(45deg)}#popup-close-btn:after{transform:rotate(-45deg)}

.item .info {
  display: none; /* Hide the info inside the item element */
}

#overlay {
  /* ... */
  display: none;
}
#overlay.open {
  display: block; /* Only show the popup when .open */
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.shopmedvet.com/images/large/COFLEX-VET4.jpg">
  <h3>Product A</h3>
  <button class="show-info-btn">Product Information</button>
  <div class="info">Some info about product A!</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.shopmedvet.com/images/large/COFLEX-VET4.jpg">
  <h3>Product B</h3>
  <button class="show-info-btn">Product Information</button>
  <div class="info">Some info about product B!</div>
</div>

<div id="overlay" title="Close">
  <div id="popup" title="">
    <div id="popup-close-btn" title="Close"></div>
    <div id="popup-content">lorem</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: im in no way  shape or form an advance developer. I know basic HTML - CSS and i just learn today that java and javascript are two different things- and that on and off function i got it from W3 -. Im learning and i cannot be more confused on what you just did, but im going to study it and understand it. i have more of a grasp on how it works.